# Converting float.hex() value to binary in Python

Tags: python

I am wondering how to convert the result returned by `float.hex()` to binary, for example, from `0x1.a000000000000p+2` to `110.1`.

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def float_to_binary(num):
    exponent=0
    shifted_num=num
    while shifted_num != int(shifted_num):        
        shifted_num*=2
        exponent+=1
    if exponent==0:
        return '{0:0b}'.format(int(shifted_num))
    binary='{0:0{1}b}'.format(int(shifted_num),exponent+1)
    integer_part=binary[:-exponent]
    fractional_part=binary[-exponent:].rstrip('0')
    return '{0}.{1}'.format(integer_part,fractional_part)

def floathex_to_binary(floathex):
    num = float.fromhex(floathex)
    return float_to_binary(num)


print(floathex_to_binary('0x1.a000000000000p+2'))    
# 110.1

print(floathex_to_binary('0x1.b5c2000000000p+1'))    
# 11.01101011100001
```

---

**Explanation**:

`float.fromhex` returns a float `num`. We'd like its binary representation.

`{0:b}.format(...)` returns binary representations of integers, but not floats.

But if we multiply the float by enough powers of 2, that is, shift the binary representation to the left enough places, we end up with an integer, `shifted_num`.

Once we have that integer, we are home free, because now we can use `{0:b}.format(...)`.

We can re-insert the decimal point (err, binary point?) by using a bit of string slicing based on the number of places we had shifted to the left (`exponent`).

Technical point: The number of digits in the binary representation of `shifted_num` may be smaller than `exponent`. In that case, we need to pad the binary representation with more 0's on the left, so binary slicing with `binary[:-exponent]` won't be empty. We manage that with `'{0:0{1}b}'.format(...)`. The `0{1}` in the format string sets the width of the formated string to `{1}`, padded on the left with zeros. (The `{1}` gets replaced by the number `exponent`.)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit, especially about the use of shifted_num with a particular exponent 20? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Qiang Li: I added some explanation. Hope it helps. I don't think my function is perfect -- I think 20 might be too small... still working on it....

Comment: @unutbu +1, it works, I still haven't precisely understood how, but it works. Though, your results have less digits (around 52 to 63 on some essays). Do you know why ?

Comment: @eyquem: I don't know what you mean (regarding "52 to 63"). Can you give an example?

Comment: @unutbu Your code is fine. I upvote. I still don't understand it thoroughly (I didn't looked in it to the hilt). I see you have changed something: having added the if instruction ``if exponent==0:`` , now it is completely correct; before that, without this condition, your code was giving weird results for big-big numbers. Now it works perfectyly

Comment: @unutbu Concerning "52 to 63", it is the length of some binary representations I obtained with my code for certain numbers, while your code was yielding shorter length of 0/1 for the same numbers. As your code wasn't OK for the big numbers, I thought it was due to your code. But  I have examined with attention the execution of mine and I see there's a problem because of the instruction ``if pdec-tin==0:`` . !! Was evident it could triggers problems !!

Comment: @unutbu I got the reason! In fact it's not the instruction ``if pdec-tin==0:`` itself that causes problem. As I said in my editing answer, there is now an instruction ``a,_,p = '{:f}'.format(fromh).partition('.')`` But , as I'm not as much skilled in using **format()** , the fact that the pattern is simply **{:f}** makes that the resulting string is limited in precision, probably by default. So when I passed the number **x = 780.2265625**, the resulting **h = x.hex() == '0x1.861d000000000p+9'** and then **float.fromhex(h) == 780.2265625**, that's right, .....

Comment: @unutbu ...but then **'{:f}'.format(float.fromhex(h))** is only **780.226562** . I had choosen the value 780.226562**5** because the part after the dot is precisely representable in binary, not approximated. But **780.226562** is no more, so the condition ``if pdec-tin==0:`` was never respected, though **pdec** and **tin** are Decimal instances, and bits were added more than the ones necessary to represent **780.2265625**. I need to put something like that ``a,_,p = '{:.15f}'.format(fromh).partition('.')`` to correct the problem, and now my code give exactly the same results as yours. Ouf !

Answer (score 4):

**Note**  that the binary form of `0x1.a000000000000p+2` isn't  `101.1` (or more exactly `0b101.1` )
but  `0b110.1`  (in my Python 2.7, binary numbers are displayed like that)

.

**First**, a useful method of float instances `float.hex()` and its inverse function, a float class method `float.fromhex()`

```
fh =  12.34.hex()
print fh
print float.fromhex(fh)
```

result

```
0x1.8ae147ae147aep+3  # hexadecimal representation of a float
12.34
```

*"Note that float.hex() is an instance method, while float.fromhex() is a class method."*

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex

.

**Secondly**, I didn't find a Python's function to transform an hexadecimal representation of a float into a binary representation of this float, that is to say with a dot ( nor than one to transform directly a decimal representation of a float into a binary one).

So I created a function for that purpose.

Before hand, this function transforms the hexadecimal representation into a decimal representation (string) of the input float.

Then there are two problems:

- how to transform the part before the dot ?
  This part being an integer, it's easy to use `bin()`
- how to transform the part after the dot ??
  The problem of this transformation has been asked several times on SO, but I didn't understand the solutions, so I wrote my own.

Then, here's the function you wish, Qiang Li:

```
def hexf2binf(x):
    '''Transforms an hexadecimal float with a dot into a binary float with a dot'''
    a,_,p = str(float.fromhex(x)).partition('.')
    # the following part transforms the part after the dot into a binary after the dot
    tinies = [ Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**i) for i in xrange(1,400)]
    bits = []
    pdec = Decimal('.'+p)
    for tin in tinies:
        if pdec-tin==0:
            bits.append('1')
            break
        elif pdec-tin>0:
            bits.append('1')
            pdec -= tin
        else:
            bits.append('0')
    pbin = ''.join(bits) # it's the binary after the dot
    # the integer before the dot is easily transformed into a binary
    return '.'.join((bin(int(a)),pbin))
```

.

In order to perform verification, I wrote a function to transform the part of a binary float after a dot into its decimal representation:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext()

getcontext().prec = 500
# precision == 500 , to be large !

tinies = [ Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**i) for i in xrange(1,400)]
com = dict((i,tin) for i,tin in enumerate(tinies,1))




def afterdotbinary2float(sbin, com = com):
    '''Transforms a binary lying after a dot into a float after a dot'''
    if sbin.startswith('0b.') or sbin.startswith('.'):
        sbin = sbin.split('.')[1]
    if all(c in '01' for c in sbin):
        return sum(int(c)*com[i] for i,c in enumerate(sbin,1))
    else:
        return None
```

.

.

**Finally**, applying these functions:

```
from decimal import Decimal

getcontext().prec = 500
# precision == 500 , to be large !


tinies = [ Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**i) for i in xrange(1,400)]
com = dict((i,tin) for i,tin in enumerate(tinies,1))


def afterdotbinary2float(sbin, com = com):
    '''Transforms a binary lying after a dot into a float after a dot'''
    if sbin.startswith('0b.') or sbin.startswith('.'):
        sbin = sbin.split('.')[1]
    if all(c in '01' for c in sbin):
        return sum(int(c)*com[i] for i,c in enumerate(sbin,1))
    else:
        return None    



def hexf2binf(x):
    '''Transforms an hexadecimal float with a dot into a binary float with a dot'''
    a,_,p = str(float.fromhex(x)).partition('.')
    # the following part transforms the float after the dot into a binary after the dot
    tinies = [ Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**i) for i in xrange(1,400)]
    bits = []
    pdec = Decimal('.'+p)
    for tin in tinies:
        if pdec-tin==0:
            bits.append('1')
            break
        elif pdec-tin>0:
            bits.append('1')
            pdec -= tin
        else:
            bits.append('0')
    pbin = ''.join(bits) # it's the binary after the dot
    # the float before the dot is easily transformed into a binary
    return '.'.join((bin(int(a)),pbin))



for n in (45.625 , 780.2265625 , 1022.796875):
    print 'n ==',n,'      transformed with its method hex() to:'
    nhexed = n.hex()
    print 'nhexed = n.hex() ==',nhexed
    print '\nhexf2binf(nhexed) ==',hexf2binf(nhexed)
    print "\nVerification:\nbefore,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')"
    before,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')
    print 'before ==',before,'   after ==',after
    print 'int(before,2) ==',int(before,2)
    print 'afterdotbinary2float(after) ==',afterdotbinary2float(after)
    print '\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n'
```

result

```
n == 45.625       transformed with its method hex() to:
nhexed = n.hex() == 0x1.6d00000000000p+5

hexf2binf(nhexed) == 0b101101.101

Verification:
before,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')
before == 0b101101    after == 101
int(before,2) == 45
afterdotbinary2float(after) == 0.625

---------------------------------------------------------------

n == 780.2265625       transformed with its method hex() to:
nhexed = n.hex() == 0x1.861d000000000p+9

hexf2binf(nhexed) == 0b1100001100.0011101

Verification:
before,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')
before == 0b1100001100    after == 0011101
int(before,2) == 780
afterdotbinary2float(after) == 0.2265625

---------------------------------------------------------------

n == 1022.796875       transformed with its method hex() to:
nhexed = n.hex() == 0x1.ff66000000000p+9

hexf2binf(nhexed) == 0b1111111110.110011

Verification:
before,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')
before == 0b1111111110    after == 110011
int(before,2) == 1022
afterdotbinary2float(after) == 0.796875

---------------------------------------------------------------
```

.

For the **two numbers**:

```
from decimal import Decimal

tinies = [ Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**i) for i in xrange(1,400)]
com = dict((i,tin) for i,tin in enumerate(tinies,1))


def hexf2binf(x, tinies = tinies):
    '''Transforms an hexadecimal float with a dot into a binary float with a dot'''
    a,_,p = str(float.fromhex(x)).partition('.')
    # the following part transforms the float after the dot into a binary after the dot
    bits = []
    pdec = Decimal('.'+p)
    for tin in tinies:
        if pdec-tin==0:
            bits.append('1')
            break
        elif pdec-tin>0:
            bits.append('1')
            pdec -= tin
        else:
            bits.append('0')
    pbin = ''.join(bits) # it's the binary after the dot
    # the float before the dot is easily transformed into a binary
    return '.'.join((bin(int(a)),pbin))


print hexf2binf('0x1.a000000000000p+2')
print
print hexf2binf('0x1.b5c2000000000p+1')
```

as a result, this displays:

```
0b110.1

0b11.011010111000010000000000000000000000010000011111100001111111101001000110110000101101110000000001111110011100110101011100011110011101111010001011111001011101011000000011001111111010111011000101000111100100110000010110001000111010111101110111011111000100100110110101011100101001110011000100000000010001101111111010001110100100101110111000111111001011101101010011011111011001010011111111010101011010110
```

Comment: @agf I know, I had seen my error. But it took me a long time to solve the problem. Now, my answer deserves its two upvotes , I think

Comment: @agf I thought you were right concerning the '0b' after a dot, so I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Given the a hexadecimal string `h`, you can find the corresponding float with

```
x = float.fromhex(h)
```

So really you're interesting in being able to produce a "fixed point" binary representation of any float.  Its possible there is no finite representation so you probably want to restrict the length it can be. (eg the binary representation of math.pi wouldn't end ...)

So something like the following might work

```
def binaryRepresentation(x, n=8):
    # the base and remainder ... handle negatives as well ...
    base = int(x)
    fraction = abs(int(round( (x - base) * (2**n) )))

    # format and remove redundant zeros
    return "{0:b}.{1:b}".format(base, fraction).rstrip("0")
```

Comment: I tried your function on the two numbers **'0x1.a000000000000p+2'** and **'0x1.b5c2000000000p+1'**. I got the error ``ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x1.a000000000000p+2'`` Then , i placed ``x = float.fromhex(h)`` in the function at the beginning (and replacing parameter **w** with **h**) and then ran the program; it yielded : **11.11011** and **11.11011**. Yes, the same. You should run a code before posting it.

Comment: @eyquem The post clearly states that `So really you're interesting in being able to produce a "fixed point" binary representation of any float` and the function provided does exactly that. Why write a function that only converts hex to binary when one that converts floats to binary is far more useful. Further `binaryRepresentation(float.fromhex('0x1.a000000000000p+2'))` and `binaryRepresentation(float.fromhex('0x1.b5c2000000000p+1'))` produce 110.1 and 11.11011 respectively.  Yes **not** the same.  You should read a posting properly before commenting on it.

Comment: _"Why write a function that only converts hex to binary when one that converts floats to binary is far more useful."_ I agree: converting "decimal" floats to binary seems to me a more common wish that converting "hexadecimal" floats into binary. The point is that the OP doesn't want the latter but the former. So , personally, I did effort to write such a function, and consequently I was presuming that your function should receive "hexadecimal" float as arguments too, not "decimal" floats. But it wasn't the case. Where's my fault for that ?

Comment: Concerning the execution of your function, it's clear I did an error.  I added ``x = float.fromhex(h)`` and I thought to replace the parameter **x** of your function with parameter **h** , but I must have tested the same value as argument, certainly the reason why I obtained two times the same value 11.11011  ; sorry for that.

Comment: So, I re-tested your function and this time I indeed obtained the values 110.1 and 11.11011 , that's right. But the value **11.11011** is certainly wrong because my function and the _unutbu_ 's function give the same result: 11.01101011100001 for '0x1.b5c2000000000p+1' which is the float **3.41998291015625** . My comment was certainly a few too much fastly written, excuse me; but your answer isn't exempted of approximation too

Answer (score 1):

Big **EDIT** about big numbers

.

The following code shows a problem with my solution in my other answer.
Note that I changed the parameter of my function **hexf2binf(floathex)** from **h** to **floathex**, to make it the same as the parameter used by *unutbu* in his function **floathex_to_binary(floathex)**

```
from decimal import Decimal,getcontext
getcontext.prec = 500
tinies = [ Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**i) for i in xrange(1,400)]
com = dict((i,tin) for i,tin in enumerate(tinies,1))

def hexf2binf(floathex, tinies = tinies):
    fromh = float.fromhex(floathex)
    print 'fromh = float.fromhex(h)    DONE'
    print 'fromh ==',fromh
    print "str(float.fromhex(floathex)) ==",str(float.fromhex(floathex))

    a,_,p = str(float.fromhex(floathex)).partition('.')
    print 'before the dot ==',a
    print 'after the dot ==',p
    # the following part transforms the float after the dot into a binary after the dot
    bits = []
    pdec = Decimal('.'+p)
    for tin in tinies:
        if pdec-tin==0:
            bits.append('1')
            break
        elif pdec-tin>0:
            bits.append('1')
            pdec -= tin
        else:
            bits.append('0')
    pbin = ''.join(bits) # it's the binary after the dot
    # the float before the dot is easily transformed into a binary
    return '.'.join((bin(int(a)),pbin))



x = x = 123456789012345685803008.0
print '   x = {:f}'.format(x)
h = x.hex()
print '   h = x.hex() ==',h

print '\nENTERING hexf2binf(floathex) with h as argument'
v = hexf2binf(h)
print '\nhexf2binf(x)==',v
```

result

```
   x = 123456789012345685803008.000000
   h = x.hex() == 0x1.a249b1f10a06dp+76

ENTERING hexf2binf(floathex) with h as argument
fromh = float.fromhex(h)    DONE
fromh == 1.23456789012e+23
str(float.fromhex(floathex)) == 1.23456789012e+23
before the dot == 1
after the dot == 23456789012e+23

hexf2binf(x)== 0b1.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

The problem is due to the instruction `str(float.fromhex(x))`  in the instruction `a,_,p = str(float.fromhex(x)).partition('.')` that produces , for a big number, a representation of **float.fromhex(x)** with an exponent.
Then THE PARTS BEFORE THE DOT (a as ante)  AND AFTER THE DOT (p as post) ARE FALSE.

Correcting this is easy: replacing the inaccurate instruction with this one:

```
a,_,p = '{:f}'.format(float.fromhex(x)).partition('.')
```

.

#### Nota bene:

> On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision
>   available for a Python float, so the value stored internally when you
>   enter the decimal number 0.1 is the binary fraction
>   0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
>   http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

That means that when a big value for a float is written in a code, its internal representation is in fact an approximation of the written value.
That is shown by the following code:

```
x1 = 123456789012345685803008.0
print 'x1 == 123456789012345685803008.0'
h1 = x1.hex()
print 'h1 = x1.hex() ==',h1
y1 = float.fromhex(h1)
print 'y1 = float.fromhex(h1) == {:f}'.format(y1)
print

x2 = 123456789012345678901234.64655
print 'x2 == 123456789012345678901234.64655'
h2 = x2.hex()
print 'h2 = x2.hex() ==',h2
y2 = float.fromhex(h2)
print 'y2 = float.fromhex(h2) == {:f}'.format(y2)
print
```

result

```
x1 == 123456789012345685803008.0
h1 = x1.hex() == 0x1.a249b1f10a06dp+76
y1 = float.fromhex(h1) == 123456789012345685803008.000000

x2 == 123456789012345678901234.64655
h2 = x2.hex() == 0x1.a249b1f10a06dp+76
y2 = float.fromhex(h2) == 123456789012345685803008.000000
```

Values of **h1** and **h2** are the same because, though different values are assigned to identifiers  *x1* and *x2* in the script, the OBJECTS **x1** and **x2** are represented with the same approximation in the machine.
The internal representation of **123456789012345685803008.0** is the exact value of **123456789012345685803008.0** and is the internal representation of **123456789012345678901234.64655** but its approximation, hence deduction of **h1** and **h2** from **x1** and **x2** gives the same value to **h1** and **h2**.

This problem exists when we write a number in decimal representation in a script.  It doesn't exist when we write a number directly in hexadecimal or binary representation.

#### What I wanted to underline

is that I wrote a function **afterdotbinary2float(sbin, com = com)** to perform verification on the results yielded by **hexf2binf( )**.  This verification works well when the number passed to  **hexf2binf( )** isn't big, but because of the internal approximation of  big numbers (= having a lot of digits), I wonder if this verification isn't distorted. Indeed, when a big number arrives in the function, it has already been approximated : the digits after the dot have been transformed into a series of zeros;
as it is shown here after:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 500
tinies = [ Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**i) for i in xrange(1,400)]
com = dict((i,tin) for i,tin in enumerate(tinies,1))


def afterdotbinary2float(sbin, com = com):
    '''Transforms a binary lying after a dot into a float after a dot'''
    if sbin.startswith('0b.') or sbin.startswith('.'):
        sbin = sbin.split('.')[1]
    if all(c in '01' for c in sbin):
        return sum(int(c)*com[i] for i,c in enumerate(sbin,1))
    else:
        return None



def hexf2binf(floathex, tinies = tinies):
    '''Transforms an hexadecimal float with a dot into a binary float with a dot'''
    a,_,p = '{:.400f}'.format(float.fromhex(floathex)).partition('.')
    # the following part transforms the float after the dot into a binary after the dot
    bits = []
    pdec = Decimal('.'+p)
    for tin in tinies:
        if pdec-tin==0:
            bits.append('1')
            break
        elif pdec-tin>0:
            bits.append('1')
            pdec -= tin
        else:
            bits.append('0')
    pbin = ''.join(bits) # it's the binary after the dot
    # the float before the dot is easily transformed into a binary
    return '.'.join((bin(int(a)),pbin))



for n in (123456789012345685803008.0, 123456789012345678901234.64655, Decimal('123456789012345.2546') ):
    print 'n == {:f}      transformed with its method hex() to:'.format(n)
    nhexed = n.hex()
    print 'nhexed = n.hex() ==',nhexed
    print '\nhexf2binf(nhexed) ==',hexf2binf(nhexed)
    print "\nVerification:\nbefore,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')"
    before,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')
    print 'before ==',before,'   after ==',after
    print 'int(before,2) ==',int(before,2)
    print 'afterdotbinary2float(after) ==',afterdotbinary2float(after)
    print '\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n'
```

result

```
n == 123456789012345685803008.000000      transformed with its method hex() to:
nhexed = n.hex() == 0x1.a249b1f10a06dp+76

hexf2binf(nhexed) == 0b11010001001001001101100011111000100001010000001101101000000000000000000000000.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Verification:
before,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')
before == 0b11010001001001001101100011111000100001010000001101101000000000000000000000000    after == 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
int(before,2) == 123456789012345685803008
afterdotbinary2float(after) == 0E-399

---------------------------------------------------------------

n == 123456789012345685803008.000000      transformed with its method hex() to:
nhexed = n.hex() == 0x1.a249b1f10a06dp+76

hexf2binf(nhexed) == 0b11010001001001001101100011111000100001010000001101101000000000000000000000000.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Verification:
before,_,after = hexf2binf(nhexed).partition('.')
before == 0b11010001001001001101100011111000100001010000001101101000000000000000000000000    after == 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
int(before,2) == 123456789012345685803008
afterdotbinary2float(after) == 0E-399

---------------------------------------------------------------

n == 123456789012345.2546      transformed with its method hex() to:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\verfitruc.py", line 41, in <module>
    nhexed = n.hex()
AttributeError: 'Decimal' object has no attribute 'hex'
```

Conclusion: testing with numbers **123456789012345685803008.0** and **123456789012345678901234.64655** makes no difference and no interest.

So, I wanted to test un-approximated numbers, and I passed a Decimal float number. As you see, the problem is that such an instance hasn't the **hex()** method.

.

Finally, I'm not entirely sure of my function for the big numbers, but it works correctly for common numbers after I corrected the inaccurate instruction.

.

### EDIT

I added '.400' in the instruction:

```
a,_,p = '{:.400f}'.format(fromh).partition('.')
```

otherwise the value of **p** could be truncated, thus giving a binary representation of a slightly different number than the one passed to the function.

I put 400 because it is the length I defined for the list **tinies** that contains the Decimal instances corresponding to 1/2 , 1/4 , 1/8 , 1/16 etc

However, though it is rare that a number with more than 400 digits after the comma has any sense, this adding remains unsatisfactory for me: the code isn't absolutely general, which is the case of *unutbu* 's code.