# How to see the binary value of float that's really stored in memory. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, binary

Is there any way to access the actual bits that are stored in memory for the floating-point variables in Python?

I'm imagining something similar to [bin()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) function (but with floats as inputs).

I came across various Python solutions to convert a floating-point number into its IEEE-754 representation (see below), but they all require several steps of computation, and I imagine one should have the ability to just read these values directly from memory - without the unnecessary manipulations. Or am I wrong? Then why is that impossible?

Here are the examples of what I've found:

- [floating -> hex IEEE 754](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-represent-floating-number-as-hexadecimal-by-ieee-754-standard/) (GeeksforGeeks)
- [Python program to convert floating to binary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-floating-to-binary/) (GeeksforGeeks):

> Python doesn’t provide any inbuilt method to easily convert floating point decimal numbers to binary number.

- [Binary representation of float in Python (bits not hex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex) (StackOverflow)
- [Converting float.hex() value to binary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666713/converting-float-hex-value-to-binary-in-python/7666995) (StackOverflow). With this approach we should first convert a float into its hex representation with the [float.hex()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex) method.

Comment: Everything in Python is an object. `float` objects in particular in CPython are just thin wrappers around C doubles

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex solves my problem. Thanks. I couldn't understand their solution at first. Should research more about `struct`.